# Sending a json object with ajax post

Tags: ajax, post, http-status-code-400, postdata

Im working on a project, where we try to exchange different parameters between the UI and a RestAPI via AJAX. The RestAPI defines how the data has to look:

[image: Parameters to send]

[image]

I tried to solve it this way:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(){
      var credentials = [
          {user_name: $("#uname").val(),
            password: $("#pwd").val()
          }
      ];
      alert(credentials);
      $.ajax({
          url:"../rest/user/login",
          type:"POST",
          data:JSON.stringify({credentials: credentials}),
          success: function(){
            window.location.href = "startrackhome.html";
          },
          error:  function error(response){
            try{
              var json = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
              if(typeof json.message === 'undefined'){
                throw new Error("Response json has no message");
              }
              else{
                alert(json.message);
              }
            }
          catch(ex){
            alert("unexpected error (code:" + response.status +")");
          }
        }

      });
   });
   });
```

The alert shows this: [object Object]

And I always get an error message (error: 400), which means that I mus have made a mistake and I think the format I'm sendig is wrong but I dont know how to fix it.

I hope you can help me! :)

Comment: I think you should not stringify the json but pass the object as is to $.ajax, and add `contentType: "application/json"`

Comment: I tried it but I still get the Error Message so thats not the solution I guess

Comment: Does your server support json requests ? if not try `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` instead and try `data: {credentials: JSON.stringify(credentials)}`

Comment: As far as I know the server supports json requests (we use that for another request). But I still tried your option and it also didn't work

Comment: Do you have an error message ? because that request is fine, it's perhaps something else, are you sure the credentials are valid ?

Comment: I did not get other error messages. I looked at the request payload and its this: credentials%5B0%5D%5Buser_name%5D=username&credentials%5B0%5D%5Bpassword%5D=password

The response is this:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at JSON.parse (&lt;anonymous&gt;)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at createStrictSyntaxError

Comment: Try to stringify the credentials then, perhaps it will work `data: {credentials: JSON.stringify(credentials)}`, because your payload seems to have plain credentials (not stringified)

Comment: After changing it to what you suggested it still looks the same

Comment: And the payload how it looks ? you should have a credentials field with a json inside. Can you call for help in your company ? because i don't think we will be able to help you further, without knowing the implementation logic of the api, and the authentication system it's difficult to help. Check the url to be sure because `../rest/user/login` seems a bit off

Comment: And also remove the array of credentials, it should be an object not an array, like so : `{user_name: '', password: ''}`

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code :

```js
// credentials is an object
var credentials = {
    user_name: $("#uname").val(),
    password: $("#pwd").val()
}
alert(credentials);
$.ajax({
    // check this url seems a bit off
    url: "../rest/user/login",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        credentials: credentials
    },
    success: function() {
        window.location.href = "startrackhome.html";
    },
    error: function error(response) {
        try {
            var json = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
            if (typeof json.message === 'undefined') {
                throw new Error("Response json has no message");
            } else {
                alert(json.message);
            }
        } catch (ex) {
            alert("unexpected error (code:" + response.status + ")");
        }
    }

});
```

in my case it makes this request :

```
fetch("https://stackoverflow.com/posts/rest/user/login", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-language": "",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"102\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"Linux\"",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
  },
  "referrer": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72620005/edit",
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": "credentials%5Buser_name%5D=test&credentials%5Bpassword%5D=test",
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "include"
});
```

```
credentials[user_name]: test
credentials[password]: test
```

which seems good, if the server needs a json, you can stringify the credentials, which gives this paylaod :

```
credentials: {"user_name":"test","password":"test"}
```

Comment: I still get the same error message and the payload is still the same. I guess I should try talking to the people that are responsible for the api. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: I think you have invalid credentials, it's the only explanation if you are still having issues, one of the two solutions should pass, either the json one, or the x-www-form-urlencoded one

Comment: I used the developer tool of chrome to find out what the problem is exactly and it says: "Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0". Can you tell me what this means? I cant find anything about it